# MySQL query for geographic midpoint

Tags: sql, mysql, spatial, latitude-longitude

I need a MySQL query (or function) to calculate the geographic midpoint of an arbitrary number of latitude/longitude coordinates. I want to use Method C (Average latitude/longitude) as described on this page http://www.geomidpoint.com/calculation.html but can't figure out how to convert this into a SQL query. I'm looking for something of the form:

select LATITUDE_AVG_FORMULA(points.latitude),LONGITUDE_AVG_FORMULA(points.longitude) from points;

Where each point in the points table has as associated latitude and longitude in decimal format. I'm hoping someone either already has a MySQL query (or function) they are using for this or have a lot more experience with geospacial calculations than I have. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What format are the lat and long values currently stored in the database?

Comment: As mentioned in my original post the lat and long values are stored as decimals. More specifically, latitude decimal(11,7) and longitude decimal (12,7). Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method C appears to be basically a weighted average.  Your question is close to MySQL syntax.  Given that these are decimal format.

If you have weights:

```
SELECT
    SUM( longitude * weight ) / SUM( weight ) AS Avg_Long,
    SUM( latitude * weight ) / SUM( weight ) AS Avg_Lat
FROM
    points
```

Or unweighted:

```
SELECT
    AVG( longitude ) AS Avg_Long,
    AVG( latitude ) AS Avg_Lat
FROM
    points
```

Your reference alludes to baseline adjustments, but I'm not sure that's needed.

Comment: That was my guess as well but from looking at the explanation I didn't know if there was something more complicated I needed to do in order to convert from decimal to cartesian coordinates in order for the calculation to be accurate. Hopefully you & I are right. Thanks for taking a look at it!